# How to find value of type from list

Tags: list, recursion, f#

So im in the early stages of learning how to use functional programming and I ran into this problem when I tried to compare a string with a string in a list, so that I could get the matching patterns.

Here is my code:

**F# Code**

```
type name = string;;
type number = string;;
type sex = string;;
type year = int;;
type interest = string list;;
type criteria = (sex * year * interest) list;;
type Register = (name * number * criteria) list;;

let reg = [("Lars","28551086",("male",1992,["soccer";"golf"])); ("Hanne","28598653",("female",1989,["cooking";"jewelry"]));
           ("Viktor","26587297",("male",1973,["clothes";"soccer"])); ("Henrik","22157864",("male",1985,["internet";"facebook"]));
           ("Lotte","23589462",("female",1997,["bombing";"internet"])); ("Susanne","25896742",("female",1923,["soccer";"cooking"]));
           ("Marie","22658943",("female",1975,["clothes";"jewelry"])) ];;

let rec findYear n = function
    | [] -> failwith("No person with that year is registrered")
    | (name,_,(_,n',_))  when n = n' -> name
    | (name,_,(_,n',_))::tail  when n <> n' -> findYear(tail);;
```

What im trying to do, is to retrieve all the people in the **reg** that has the same name as the one im searching for. 
So a F# Interactive call could be:

```
findYear 1992;;
```

And then it should give me the details of the persons with that year. Im not sure how to search through my **reg**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just forgot the `n` (and the tail of a list) here:

```
let rec findYear n = function
    | [] -> failwith("No person with that year is registrered")
    | (name,_,(_,n',_))  when n = n' -> name // forgot tail
    | (name,_,(_,n',_))::tail  when n <> n' -> findYear(tail) // forgot n here
```

(should have gotten an error

try this:

```
let rec findYear n = function
    | [] -> failwith("No person with that year is registrered")
    | ((name,_,(_,n',_))::_)  when n = n' -> name
    | ((_,_,(_,n',_))::tail)  when n <> n' -> findYear n tail
```

### making this a bit better

#### you don't need to check again

you don't need to recheck the year if the second pattern did not match:

```
let rec findYear n = function
    | [] -> failwith("No person with that year is registrered")
    | ((name,_,(_,n',_))::_)  when n = n' -> name
    | (_::tail) -> findYear n tail
```

#### `option` is better than an exception

The way you handle the case where you don't find a person with this year tells us that your function is "partial" (does not return for every input) - so just make it total again by using `option`:

```
let rec findYear n = function
    | [] -> None
    | ((name,_,(_,n',_))::_) when n = n' -> Some name
    | (_::tail) -> findYear n tail
```

This will not throw and tell the user: *"hey I might fail so better handle this!"*

#### use records / ADTs

While your tuples are fine they are not really readable (hard to check if your pattern is ok for example) - why not use records and algebraic-data-types:

```
type Name = string
type Number = string
type Gender = Male | Female // add more if you need
type Year = int
type Interests = string list
type Criteria = { gender : Gender; year : Year; interests : Interests }
type Register = { name : Name; number : Number; criteria : Criteria }

let reg = 
  [ { name = "Lars"
    ; number = "28551086"
    ; criteria = { gender = Male; year = 1992; interests = ["soccer";"golf"] }
    }
    // ...
]
```

and use this:

```
let rec findYear n = 
    function
    | [] -> None
    | (reg::_) when reg.criteria.year = n' 
       -> Some reg
    | (_::regs) 
       -> findYear n regs
```

#### use the `List` module

What you do here is a **very** common pattern and it's already implemented (`List.tryFind`) - so why not use it?

```
let findYear n = 
    let hasYear (reg : Register) = reg.criteria.year = n
    List.tryFind hasYear
```

of course you can add the missing parameter if you don't really understand partial application yet:

```
let findYear n regs = 
    let hasYear (reg : Register) = reg.criteria.year = n
    List.tryFind hasYear regs
```

#### finally let's give this a better name

this is of course just me not liking `findYear` if you really find a registration

```
// rest is the same
type Registration = { name : Name; number : Number; criteria : Criteria }

let firstRegistrationWithYear year = 
    let hasYear (reg : Register) = reg.criteria.year = year
    List.tryFind hasYear
```

### finding all registrations for one year

```
let filterRegistrationWithYear year = 
    let hasYear (reg : Register) = reg.criteria.year = year
    List.filter hasYear
```

or if you want a (tail-recursive) implementation using continuation-passing style (the other answer has the accumulator aproach):

```
let filterYear n regs = 
    let rec filter regs cont =
       match regs with
       | [] -> cont []
       | (reg::regs) when reg.criteria.year = n' 
          -> filter regs (fun res -> reg::res |> cont)
       | (_::regs) 
          -> filter regs cont
    filter regs id
```

remark:

I would not advise implementing this kind of stuff yourself - it's better to use the provided stuff from `List` (it's for example more performant as this, because I tried to show you how to do it CPS-style)

Comment: This is good, I will accept is as the answer. Thank you for the explanation aswell. Im not sure what the "Some name" is doing under records/ADT method - Can you explain?

Comment: Nevermind I found out :) Thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: I just found out that it only finds one person in the register if it equals the year. It should give me all the matching patterns ^^

Comment: yeah - your question did as well so I thought this is ok - but the solution is easy: change `List.tryFind hasYear` into `List.filter hasYear` in the last part ;)

Comment: ... of course you might want to change it's name yet again ;)

Comment: Can you make somewhat the same changes in the findYear function under Records/ADTs ? I would like to make it happen without list library :)

Comment: sure - but Petr already showed you how to do this - I give you another implementation though

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use recursion, you can add additional parameter (accumulator), to collect results:

```
let rec findYear n acc = function
    | [] -> acc
    | ((name,_,(_,n',_)) as h)::tail  when n = n' -> findYear n (h::acc) tail 
    | h::tail -> findYear n acc tail
```

And call it this way:

```
findYear 1973 [] reg
```

Or you could use the 'filter' function from the List library functions:

```
let findYear' n lst =
    lst |> List.filter (fun (name,_,(_,n',_)) -> n = n')
```

And call it this way:

```
findYear' 1973 reg
```